# setter method for hash with send()

Tags: ruby

Is it possible in Ruby to call setter method for hash with send method?
Just like I can do this:

```
h = {a: "a", b: "b"}
h.send(:[], :a)
```

and GET value `"a"` out of this hash, can I set value for key `:a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The method then is `[]=`

Example:

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
hash.send :[]=, :a, 3
hash # => {:a => 3, :b => 2}
```